# 960gs for smartphone

Tags: html, css, smartphone, 960.gs

I'm using 960 grid system for designing html pages for my app. While designing I'm thinking that if a smartphone optimized version of 960 or similar grid system exists. Then it will be easier for me to support smartphones as well.

Anyone have any idea on 960 gs for smartphone?

Answer (score 0):

http://adapt.960.gs/ looks like it will give you the functionality you need. You can still use the grid system, but as the user's resolution changes it will load in the correct stylesheets. A JavaScript solution though, rather than just CSS

Comment: actually the design is made according to 960's 16 column layout. So if it will be the best if there is a 16 cols 960 gs for smartphone

Comment: nothing wrong, just we wanted to make it smartphone suitable. we wanted that in smartphone every column will show one bellow another

Comment: ah ok, the question makes more sense, but I'm not sure how you can combine the just the 960gs and what you require for the mobile view because of how the grid system work. I've amended my answer.